# Video/Slides of the September 2013 SDL Tridion Community Webinar now available

Tags: discussion

The video and sldies of September's SDL Tridion Community Webinar are now available at http://webinars.julianwraith.com/2013/07/31/september-2013-webinar/

Two sessions were presented in September's webinar:

1. Session One: OData Query Extension. An extension to the Content Delivery Web Service that allows queries to be passed to the service using the $filter parameter.
2. Session Two: REL Standard Tag Library. A library of REL tags similar to JSTL (JSP Standard Tag Library) providing common tag templating functionality such as forEach, if, choose, when, otherwise, XML/XSL transformations, et al.